# Moving an overflow listbox down as each checkbox is AUTO unchecked by loop

Tags: javascript, css, loops, listbox

OK, so the title sounds complicated, but the idea of what i want to do is actually very simple.

I have a listbox populated auto by a loop. Something like this..

```
TICKBOX | VALUE |
TICKBOX | VALUE |
TICKBOX | VALUE |
```

Its scrollable, but often contains many items, sometimes hundreds.

I have another loop that unchecks each checkbox as it goes through them, around 1 per second or so.

As it stands, the checkboxes get unchecked as each is processed, but I want to automatically scroll the box so the bottom item is always the next one to be processed, or the next one with a still ticked box.

Anyone have any ideas? I have tried `scrollTop` and stuff, but I'm not great with javascript/CSS.

EDIT: I tried some things but didnt even get close. I will add a small piece of code, but it is from 20'000 line script so probably wont make much sense. Feel free to jiggle it about and stuff.

```
    m += '<DIV style="max-height:220px; overflow-y:auto;">';
    m += '<TABLE align=center cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0></td><TD width=15><input type=checkbox id=pbsrcScout_All></td><TD>COLUMN 2</td></tr>';
    var coordlist = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13"] // just made this up so it makes some small sense.
    for (i = 0; i < coordlist.length; i++) {
    var addOn = coordlist[i];
    m += '<TABLE align=center cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>'
    m += '<TR><TD><INPUT type=checkbox id="pbsrcScoutCheck_' + coordlist[i] + '"></td><TD>' + coordlist[i] + '</td><TD><DIV id=statusMessage_' + addOn + '></div></td></tr>';
    }
    m += '</table>'
    m += '</table></div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I understood your question properly. If you're happy using jQuery you could try the following.  For this to work you will need to give the main containing div a unique ID. I used 'parent' in this example.

You said you have a loop that checks each checkbox every 1 second, so I used setInterval to emulate the loop.

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/qvfrb/1/)

```
var checkboxes = $('[id^=pbsrcScoutCheck_]'), // find all checkboxes
    checkboxIndex = 0, // so we know what box needs to be unchecked next
    parent = $("#parent"), // the main parent div container. 
    interval;

// emulate you're loop that checks each box
interval = setInterval(function() {
    var checkbox = $(checkboxes[checkboxIndex]).attr('checked', false);
    if (checkbox.position().top + (checkbox.height() * 3) > parent.height()) {
        parent.stop(true, true).animate({
            scrollTop: "+=" + (checkbox.height() * 3)
        }, 500);
    }

    checkboxIndex++;
    if (checkboxIndex > checkboxes.length) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 1000);
```